# LinearLayout layout_gravity bottom issue

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, gravity, layout-gravity

There is my code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_home"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.30"
    android:gravity="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.70"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayBtnUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btntest"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fa" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btntest1"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fas" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btntest2"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fas" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayBtnDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btntest3"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fas" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btntest4"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fa" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tset5"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fsa" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id"@+id/llBot" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is  that the last LinearLayout (with the id "llBot") touch the bottom of his parent.

So I've tried :

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

But still; it has no effect. My LinearLayout still touch the previous Linearlayout.

Thx !

Comment: not possible this way. use a spacer

Comment: Try outer layout as RelativeLayout and then set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: Ow... Isen't it possible to do it with LinearLayout only ? if no, why ?

Comment: You've got for too many LinearLayouts going on there than is efficient, you should use a RelativeLayout. It gives you more control than a LinearLayout will, which is intended to layout things one after the other.

Comment: I can't explain _why_ it's not possible.  It's not possible because Android is designed this way.

Comment: You can use the `RelativeLayout` as your root layout instead of `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out below layout code i have done relevant changes:

> ```
>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="0.30"
>     android:gravity="center" />
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="0.70"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/llayBtnUp"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center" >
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/btntest"
>             android:layout_width="48dp"
>             android:layout_height="48dp"
>             android:layout_margin="10dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/btntest1"
>             android:layout_width="48dp"
>             android:layout_height="48dp"
>             android:layout_margin="10dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/buttonred" />
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/btntest2"
>             android:layout_width="48dp"
>             android:layout_height="48dp"
>             android:layout_margin="10dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/border" />
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/llayBtnDown"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center" >
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/btntest3"
>             android:layout_width="48dp"
>             android:layout_height="48dp"
>             android:layout_margin="10dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/download" />
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/btntest4"
>             android:layout_width="48dp"
>             android:layout_height="48dp"
>             android:layout_margin="10dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/buttonred" />
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/tset5"
>             android:layout_width="48dp"
>             android:layout_height="48dp"
>             android:layout_margin="10dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>     </LinearLayout>        
>    </LinearLayout>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/test"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="100dp"
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/button1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>             android:text="Button" />
>     </LinearLayout>
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: But, what did you exactly change ?

Comment: Well nothing you can just check out your last LinearLayout you'll get the difference . :)